# Is there a way to merge multiple list index by index?

Tags: python, list, indexing

For example, I have three lists (of the same length)

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [a,b,c]
C = [x,y,z]
```

and i want to merge it into something like:
[[1,a,x],[2,b,y],[3,c,z]].

Here is what I have so far:

```
define merger(A,B,C):
  answer = 
  for y in range (len(A)):
    a = A[y]
    b = B[y]
    c = C[y]
    temp = [a,b,c]
    answer = answer.extend(temp)
  return answer
```

Received error:

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'

Comment: To directly answer your question answer = [] not answer =  though I am surprised that you did not get a syntax error but maybe that is swallowed by your function?  also extend works in place so you need to do answer.extend(something) not answer = answer.extend()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like your code is meant to say `answer = []`, and leaving that out will cause problems. But the major problem you have is this:

```
answer = answer.extend(temp)
```

`extend` *modifies `answer`* and returns None. Leave this as just `answer.extend(temp)` and it will work. You likely also want to use the `append` method rather than `extend` - append puts *one object* (the list `temp`) at the end of `answer`, while `extend` appends *each item* of temp individually, ultimately giving the flattened version of what you're after: `[1, 'a', 'x', 2, 'b', 'y', 3, 'c', 'z']`.

But, rather than reinventing the wheel, this is exactly what the builtin [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) is for:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> B = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> C = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> list(zip(A, B, C))
[(1, 'a', 'x'), (2, 'b', 'y'), (3, 'c', 'z')]
```

Note that in Python 2, `zip` returns a list of tuples; in Python 3, it returns a lazy iterator (ie, it builds the tuples as they're requested, rather than precomputing them). If you want the Python 2 behaviour in Python 3, you pass it through `list` as I've done above. If you want the Python 3 behaviour in Python 2, use the function [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) from itertools.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong what is needed is append not extend and your solution still is not there as you have a list of tuples

Comment: Ah, I was not familiar with the extend function. I understand the error now thanks!

Answer (score 8):

To get a **list of lists**, you can use the built-in function [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) and *list comprehension* to convert each element of the result of `zip()` from a `tuple`to a `list`:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [4, 5, 6]
C = [7, 8, 9]

X = [list(e) for e in zip(A, B, C,)]

print X
>>> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing this for class and not learning all of the tricks that make Python a great tool here is what you need.  You had two problems, first if you want to extend then you do it in place but your desired result shows that you want to append, not extend

```
def merger(A,B,C):
    answer = []
    for y in range (len(A)):
        a=A[y]
        b=B[y]
        c=C[y]
        temp = [a,b,c]
        answer.append(temp)
   return answer


>>> answer
[[1, 'a', 'x'], [2, 'b', 'y'], [3, 'c', 'z']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering the same thing. I'm a total noob using code academy. This is what i came up to combine two lists index at index

```
toppings = ['pepperoni', 'pineapple', 'cheese', 'sausage', 'olives', 'anchovies',    'mushrooms']

prices = [2,6,1,3,2,7,2]

num_pizzas = len(toppings)

print("We sell "+str(num_pizzas)+" different kinds of pizza!")

***pizzas = list(zip(toppings, prices))***

print (pizzas)
```

the list pizzas printed out ...[('pepperoni', 2), ('pineapple', 6), ('cheese', 1), ('sausage', 3), ('olives', 2), ('anchovies', 7), ('mushrooms', 2)]